# my class can't use try catch block when returning values

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

How to use try catch block within a class that you created, i have used  methods that return values. so when i try to use try catch block it says an Error it says not all code paths return a value.

```
public int Save_Del_Up(string query)
{
   try
   {
     con.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
     int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();

     return result;
   }
   catch ()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Think about what's returned if you catch an exception (nothing).

Comment: 'int result;
            try
            {


                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


            return result;


            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return result;
            }' and still gives the error

Comment: Post all code in the question. And what's the significance of that code? Have you run it? What does it do?

Comment: In a case like this, you may be better off letting the exception propagate. What should be returned if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error says you need to return something from the catch block

```
public int Save_Del_Up(string query)
     try
     {    
       con.Open();
       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
       int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       return result;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
    finally
    {
     con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it works. i didn't think it of that way

Comment: @Nimsara please mark your question as answered if it was answered,

Comment: how to do that im new to stack overflow